# How to shorten this code in vb.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net

In my code I want to shorten for each part that I used ".element("Landlord)" and ".element("Others"). I mean I want to kinda factorize those duplicated part with any other statement or loops

my xml file is:

```
<root>
  <House Code="1">
    <Landlord>
      <Name>Alireza</Name>
      <Phone>012345</Phone>
    </Landlord>
    <Others>
      <Remarks>---</Remarks>
      <Status>AV</Status>
    </Others>
  </House>
</root>
```

and here is my code:

```
    Dim houseEle As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
          From _codeNo In RHEle...<House> _
          Where _codeNo.@Code = "1"
          Select _codeNo


    For Each ele In houseEle
        Dim elName As String = ele.Element("Landlord").Element("Name").Value
        txtOwner.Text = elName

        Dim elPhone As String = ele.Element("Landlord").Element("Phone").Value
        txtPhone.Text = elPhone


        Dim elRemark As String = ele.Element("Others").Element("Remarks").Value
        txtDescribe.Text = elRemark

        Dim elRs = ele.Element("Others").Element("Status").Value
        txtStatus.Text = elRs

    Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply using temporary variable?

```
 For Each ele In houseEle
    Dim landlordElement = ele.Element("Landlord")
    txtOwner.Text = landlordElement.Element("Name").Value
    txtPhone.Text = landlordElement.Element("Phone").Value
    txtMobile.Text = landlordElement.Element("Mobile").Value

    Dim othersElement = ele.Element("Others")
    txtDescribe.Text = othersElement.Element("Remarks").Value
    txtStatus.Text = othersElement.Element("Status").Value
Next
```

I would also suggest revising your naming convention. For example:

```
For Each houseElement In houseElements
```

looks much better.

If you want to shorten it further, create a `Dictionary` that will map XML element name to control and just iterate it. Hence, create it somewhere within your class (to make it reusable)

```
Dim mapping As Dictionary(Of String, Control) = New Dictionary(Of String, Control)() From
{
    {"Name", txtOwner},
    {"Phone", txtPhone},
    {"Mobile", txtMobile}
}
```

and then just use this mapping:

```
mapping.Select(Function(p) p.Value.Text = landlordElement.Element(p.Key).Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

```vb
For Each ele In houseEle

  Dim landlord = ele.Element("Landlord")  

  txtOwner.Text = landlord.Element("Name").Value

  txtPhone.Text = landlord.Element("Phone").Value

  'etc

  Dim others = ele.Element("Others")

  'etc
```

Should do it.

Comment: Yes this is on of the way but is there any other way like declare an other IEnumerable(Of XElement) variable and with another for loop get its element like how I get the elements from HouseEle

Comment: @EmPlusPlus, I've provided you an example how you can do it